# 1080p 10bit MKV Video is Choppy but Has Smaller File-size?

Tags: video, graphics-card, cpu, gpu, bitrate

I've tried VLC, MPC-HC with LAV and CCCP but nothing worked for 1080p 10bit MKV. The video is not always choppy but only during some particular scenes with high content bitrate.

I've got 2 versions of the same video, 720p 8bit and 1080p 10bit. The 720p 8bit file has larger size but plays smoothly while the other one goes choppy. How is this possible?

Is there any solution to this choppiness?

By the way, 1080p 8bit videos are ok.

I'm using Dell Inspiron 1525.

- Windows Vista Home Premium.
- Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family.
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Due CPU T5750 @ 2.00GHz 2.00 GHz
- Memory(RAM): 3.00GB
- System Type: 32-bit Operating System
- Intel Graphics Media Accelerator X3100 Dynamic Video Memory
  Technology 4.0
- DAC type: Internal
- Approx. Total Memory: 358MB

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is the computer, its not exactly a high end computer, the Mobile Intel CPU/Intel Graphics Media Accelerator are a pretty good indicator. Test those videos on a higher end computer, i'm sure they will run fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your current PC, unfortunately the answer is no.  As you've pretty much proven the CPU can't cope.

Comment: The file size is a direct result of the bitrate over time.

Comment: not necessarily, if everything else is equal then yes. But codecs, differing encoding parameters and compression could all cases where a lower bitrate file is larger.  And the poster just gives the resolution, colour depth and the container format.

Comment: Bitrate is defined as bits per second. As such, the file size is Bitrate * Length (in seconds). There's simply nothing to discuss here, it's just a fact. This also has nothing to do with resolution or codecs or anything. Also, the bitrate makes no statement as to the complexity of the algorithms used.

Comment: Ok, whatever, I've removed the comment. From the evidence we have though, it does still look like that the PC can't handle the decoding of the higher quality file.